# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})

Tags: c#, json, serialization, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Please Help me out i am new in xamarin.forms and C# i have try every solution which is given in stackoverflow but cannot avail to solve

```
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
 {
   var response = httpClient.GetAsync(Url).Result;
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      var responseContent = response.Content;
      string contents = await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
      List<abcModel> tm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<abcModel>>(contents);
      abcMaster = new ObservableCollection<SummaryModel>();
      var c = tm[0].SSum.Count();
   }
}
```

Model

```
public class abcModel
{
  public List<SSum> SSum { get; set; }
}
public class SSum
{
  public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

My Json

```
{"a":[{"SSum":[{"Name":"Earth"}]}]}
```

Error:-

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[abcModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you obviously just want to deserialize a nested part of your json, do it like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<abcModel>>>(json);
```

Comment: i m try to count the total value present in json inside SSum part how i can get

Comment: unclear what you're asking... sum up the count? `var sum = result["a"].Sum(x => x.SSum.Count);`?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `a` property in your JSON. You can deserialize into a class that has that property:

```
public class MyType
{
    public List<abcModel> A { get; set; }
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json);
```

Or skip that property all together ([@stefankmitph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30916268/497356)'s answer works well), here's another alternative:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

List<abcModel> model = obj["a"].ToObject<List<abcModel>>();
```

Just a note: normally C# classes are `PascalCased`.

Comment: i m try to count the total value present in json inside SSum part how i can get

Comment: @AtulDhanuka: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for-- are you looking for `tm.Sum(i => i.SSum.Count)`?

Comment: ya total count of the tm

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the JSON string you should use a generator like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to create the response DTO. This will prevent mistakes in what is a collection versus single object.

```
public class SSum
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    public List<SSum> SSum { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<A> A { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize the complete object:

```
tm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(contents);
```