# Error consuming Web API with ASP.NET MVC - "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object"

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am consuming a Web API, but when serializing I get this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Covid.Models.RegionsModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'data', line 1, position 8.

I read several possible solutions, in questions that have already been asked but could not get it to work.

[JSON.NET DeserializeObject to List of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012335/json-net-deserializeobject-to-list-of-objects)

[Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916211/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-namevalue)

If you could help me please, I have really tried for 3 days but I can't solve it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;
using Covid.Models;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Covid.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        string Baseurl = "https://covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/regions";

        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            try
            {
                List<RegionsModel> region = new List<RegionsModel>();

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-key", "32ac4c9518msh7fb8f6c7a05eb7bp1178dbjsn193f09c779d6");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-host", "covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("regions");

                    if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var response = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        //var ObjMovmientos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RegionsModel>>(response);
                        var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RegionsModel>>(response);
                        region = objResponse1;
                    }

                    return View(region);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

The model class is:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Covid.Models
{
    public class RegionsModel
    {
        public RegionModel[] data { get; set; }  

        public class RegionModel
        {
            [JsonProperty("iso")]
            public string Iso { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "iso": "CHN",
            "name": "China"
        },
        {
            "iso": "TWN",
            "name": "Taipei and environs"
        },
        {
            "iso": "USA",
            "name": "US"
        },
        {
            "iso": "JPN",
            "name": "Japan"
        },
        {
            "iso": "WSM",
            "name": "Samoa"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RegionsModel>>(response.data);`?

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo -- how would that work? `response` is a `string`.

Comment: @Andy you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegionsModel` already contains a property that defines an array, so this is wrong:

```
var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RegionsModel>>(response);
```

It should be:

```
var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegionsModel>(response);
```

Also, your method is already asynchronous. So instead of this:

```
var response = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Do this:

```
var response = await Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Finally, change this:

```
List<RegionsModel> region = new List<RegionsModel>();
// ...
region = objResponse1;
```

To this:

```
List<RegionModel> region = new List<RegionModel>();
// ...
region = objResponse1.data.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it already worked for me with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line,

```
 var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RegionsModel>>(response);
```

To

```
 var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegionsModel>(response);
```

Reason is because your json is of an object, data ,that has an array of objects...